# How to build facebook applications to run a contest?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

what is the correct flow in some campaigns like cocacola or levis or any other big brands -- 'like' a page first or authenticate an app -- or do we need an app at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "'like' a page first or authenticate an app -- or do we need an app at
>   all?"

Yes, you will need an app.  I presume you will have that app setup as a Page Tab.  To force the user to like the page first, you can use the signed request parameter that get's posted to the iframed url of the page tab.  Decode that and it will indicate if the user has liked your page.  If you want to limit to one entry per userId, then you will need to ask for the user to authenticate your app. And then you can get their Id to use as a key on your storage table.

Answer (score 0):

The correct flow would be what the client desires ... usually you would need an app.